# Tensorflow Embeddings best practice with Estimator

Tags: python, tensorflow

I have a CNN for CIFAR-10 dataset with layers:

```
[IN] -> [CONV] -> [POOL] -> [CONV] -> [POOL] -> [FC] -> [DROPOUT] -> [LOGITS] -> [OUT]
                                                                 \-> [EMBEDDINGS]
```

Estimator code:

```
config = tf.contrib.learn.RunConfig(save_checkpoints_secs=30)

# Create the Estimator
classifier = tf.estimator.Estimator(model_fn=inference, config=config, model_dir=LOG_DIR)
train_images, train_labels, train_labels_onehot = Utils.load_training_data()

hooks = [
    # logging hook
    tf.train.LoggingTensorHook(tensors=tensors_to_log, every_n_iter=50),
]

train_input_fn = tf.estimator.inputs.numpy_input_fn(x={'x': train_images}, y=train_labels)

classifier.train(input_fn=train_input_fn, steps=FLAGS.steps, hooks=hooks)
```

Inference function code:

```
def inference(self, features, labels, mode):
    try:
        images = tf.cast(features['x'], tf.float32)
        # Input Layer
        with tf.name_scope('Data'):
            input_layer = tf.reshape(images, [-1, img_width, img_height, num_channels])

        # Convolutional Layer 1
        with tf.variable_scope('ConvLayer1'):
            conv1 = tf.layers.conv2d(inputs=input_layer, filters=32, kernel_size=[5, 5], 
                                     padding="same", activation=tf.nn.relu)
            pool1 = tf.layers.max_pooling2d(inputs=conv1, pool_size=[2, 2], strides=2)

        logging.info('Convolutional Layer 1 build successful..')

        # Convolutional Layer 1
        with tf.variable_scope('ConvLayer2'):
            conv2 = tf.layers.conv2d(inputs=pool1, filters=64, kernel_size=[5, 5], 
                                     padding="same", activation=tf.nn.relu)
            pool2 = tf.layers.max_pooling2d(inputs=conv2, pool_size=[2, 2], strides=2)

        logging.info('Convolutional Layer 2 build successful..')

        # Fully Connected Layer
        with tf.variable_scope('FullyConnectedLayer'):
            pool2_flat = tf.reshape(pool2, [-1, 8 * 8 * 64])
            dense = tf.layers.dense(inputs=pool2_flat, units=1024, activation=tf.nn.relu)
            dropout = tf.layers.dropout(inputs=dense, rate=0.4, 
                                        training=(mode == tf.estimator.ModeKeys.TRAIN))

        logging.info('Fully Connected Layer build successful..')

        tf.summary.histogram('dropout', dropout)

        # Logits Layer
        logits = tf.layers.dense(inputs=dropout, units=10)

        tf.summary.histogram('logits', logits)

        logging.info('Logits Layer build successful..')

        predictions = {
            # Generate predictions (for PREDICT and EVAL mode)
            "classes": tf.argmax(input=logits, axis=1),
            # Add `softmax_tensor` to the graph. It is used for PREDICT and by the
            # `logging_hook`.
            "probabilities": tf.nn.softmax(logits, name="softmax_tensor")
        }

        if mode == tf.estimator.ModeKeys.PREDICT:
            return tf.estimator.EstimatorSpec(mode=mode, predictions=predictions, 
                                              evaluation_hooks=[])

        # Calculate Loss (for both TRAIN and EVAL modes)
        onehot_labels = tf.one_hot(indices=tf.cast(labels, tf.int32), depth=10)
        loss = tf.losses.softmax_cross_entropy(onehot_labels=onehot_labels,
                                               logits=logits)

        tf.summary.histogram('loss', loss)

        logging.info('Losses build successful..')

        # Configure the Training Op (for TRAIN mode)
        if mode == tf.estimator.ModeKeys.TRAIN:
            learning_rate = tf.train.exponential_decay(start_learning_rate, 
                                tf.train.get_global_step(), 1000, 0.9, staircase=True)
            optimizer = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(learning_rate=learning_rate)
            train_op = optimizer.minimize(loss=loss, global_step=tf.train.get_global_step())
            return tf.estimator.EstimatorSpec(mode=mode, loss=loss, train_op=train_op,
                                              scaffold=tf.train.Scaffold(
                                                  summary_op=tf.summary.merge_all(),
                                              ))

        # Add evaluation metrics (for EVAL mode)
        accuracy = tf.metrics.accuracy(labels=labels, predictions=predictions["classes"])

        tf.summary.histogram('accuracy', accuracy)

        logging.info('Accuracy metric build successful..')

        return tf.estimator.EstimatorSpec(mode=mode, loss=loss,
                                      train_op=train_op,
                                      scaffold=tf.train.Scaffold(
                                          summary_op=tf.summary.merge_all()
                                      ))
```

I am trying to work with Embeddings Visualization in tensorflow and here I want to visualize dropout output as embeddings.

Code that I've found to use embeddings:

```
sess = tf.InteractiveSession()

# Input set for Embedded TensorBoard visualization
# Performed with cpu to conserve memory and processing power
with tf.device("/cpu:0"):
    embedding = tf.Variable(self._data, trainable=False, name='embedding')

sess.run(embedding.initializer)

writer = tf.summary.FileWriter(LOG_DIR + '/projector', sess.graph)

config = projector.ProjectorConfig()
embed = config.embeddings.add()
embed.tensor_name = embedding.name

embed.metadata_path = os.path.join(LOG_DIR + '/projector/metadata.tsv')

embed.sprite.image_path = os.path.join(DATA_DIR + '/cifar_10k_sprite.png')
embed.sprite.single_image_dim.extend([img_width, img_height])

projector.visualize_embeddings(writer, config)

saver = tf.train.Saver([embedding])
saver.save(sess, os.path.join(LOG_DIR, 'projector/a_model.ckpt'))
```

It does not work in my case, because I am using Estimator class and I have not access to the session.

Ways that I've tried:

1. Pass numpy.array variable to the model_fn of Estimator where I can set the value to that variable and then pass that variable to SessionRunHook where I can access session and save data to the file. Did not work because all arguments passed to the Estimator become tensors. So that way does not work cause I'm already have dropout layer tensors.
2. Create global variable where I can put all values of dropout layer. Did not work too because for that approach I need to access tensors values.

As far as I understood Estimator architecture the main problem is to get dropout layer output signals to the out of the Estimator and pass it somehow to the SessionRunHook to save them as Embeddings. But I think it's not the best way.

What is the right way of using Embeddings in Estimator?

Comment: SessionRunHooks are the right way to get arbitrary ops to run, like your saver here.

Comment: @AlexandrePassos yes, I've tried that way, but the problem is that when I'm trying to create tf.Variable from dropout tensor the model has stopped with output: 
2017-12-01 10:36:37.578243: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1120] Creating TensorFlow device (/device:GPU:0) -> (device: 0, name: GeForce GTX 1080 Ti, pci bus id: 0000:02:00.0, compute capability: 6.1)

Comment: this looks like queuerunners haven't started when you're trying to fetch something

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how I did it guys (but it may be not the most efficient way):

SessinRunHook:

```
import tensorflow as tf

from classes.Utils import Utils


class EmbeddingSaverHook(tf.train.SessionRunHook):

    def __init__(self, values, labels, captions):
        self._saver = None

        self._classes = Utils.get_classnames()

        self._dense3 = None
        self._labels = None

        self._emb_values = values
        self._emb_labels = labels
        self._emb_captions = captions

    def begin(self):
        self._dense3 = tf.get_default_graph().get_tensor_by_name("dense3/BiasAdd:0")

        self._labels = tf.get_default_graph().get_tensor_by_name("labels:0")

    def before_run(self, run_context):
        return tf.train.SessionRunArgs([self._dense3, self._labels])

    def after_run(self, run_context, run_values):
        self._emb_values.extend(run_values[0][0])
        self._emb_labels.extend(run_values[0][1])
        self._emb_captions.extend([self._classes[x] for x in run_values[0][1]])

    def end(self, session):
        pass
```

Full code you can see [in my github repo](https://github.com/smivv/python-tensorflow-cifar-10/)